# Thumbnail Upload Warning getimagesize() warning: Filename cannot be empty

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add a auto-check thumbnail size function to my WordPress website, if the thumbnail size is less than 770px * 400px, it will not displayed on the top of the articles.

so I replace the original code：

```
<?php if( has_post_thumbnail() && ! has_post_format(‘video’) && ! has_post_format(‘audio’) && ! has_post_format(‘gallery’) ) : ?>
```

with

```
<?php
$display_thumbnail = true;
$thumbnail_size = getimagesize( wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) );
if ($thumbnail_size[0] < 770 || $thumbnail_size[0] < 400) {
$display_thumbnail = false;
}
?>
<?php if( has_post_thumbnail() && ! has_post_format('video') && ! has_post_format('audio') && ! has_post_format('gallery') && $display_thumbnail ) : ?>
```

Then the error occur: under the original code, if I didn't upload an image, it will display nothing; but under the new code, if I didn't upload an image, it will show the warning

```
Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Filename cannot be empty on...
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: I assume you meet $thumbnail_size[1] < 400

Comment: better use wp_get_attachment_image_src...

Comment: I've just rewritten it with wp_get_attachment_image_src()
Tell me if it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<?php
if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
    $attachment_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full' );
    $display_thumbnail = is_array($attachment_src)
                        && $attachment_src[1] >= 770
                        && $attachment_src[2] >= 400;
}
?>
<?php if( has_post_thumbnail() && ! has_post_format('video') && ! has_post_format('audio') && ! has_post_format('gallery') && $display_thumbnail ) : ?>
```

Edited: added 'full' argument to get the full size uploaded image.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried the code you posted, but it seems not work, the warning says "Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Filename cannot be empty...on line 24". the 24 line's code is `$thumbnail_size = getimagesize( $attached_url );`

Comment: wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) is supposed to return false if there is no image... http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url

Comment: try putting `die(wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ))` before you click post see what that gives you :-/
perhaps replace `($attachment_url == false ? false : true)`
with `(empty($attachment_url) ? false : true)`

Comment: Thank you so much Gibbs. I've tried the code you updated with `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`. No error occurs, but the featured images won't be displayed in a single article even the size is 770*400 or larger.

Comment: Do you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: need to see what `wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id() )` returns. try to add `print_r($attachment_src);` and see what you get in return

Comment: Array ( [0] => http://demo.hkci.org.hk/wp-content/uploads/liujintu-110x110.png [1] => 110 [2] => 110 [3] => 1 )

Hi, I've added `print_r($attachment_src);` and it returns:

 `Array ( [0] => The Image URL [1] => 110 [2] => 110 [3] => 1 )`

Comment: so this is an image of 110x110, how about having an image of 770x400 ?
try `wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full' )` to get the original uplaoded image

Comment: Actually, the feature image size is 770x400, I don't know why it resize the image to 110*110. But The issue has been solved by replace `wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id()` with `wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), ‘full’`. Thank you so much!

Comment: it's because the wp_get_attachment_image_src function returns by default the 'thumbnail' image.
Later in your code, you could call that function passing a array to force the size you want `wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), array(770, 400) )`  not sure that it'll do really what you would want tho :-/